# CollapsiblePane do not expand/collapse by mouse or respond to mouse

Tags: python, wxpython

I tried to use CollapsiblePane component of wxPython toolkit. I add 2 checkboxes directly in panel and 2 checkboxes under a CollapsiblePane which is placed in panel. My problem is that collapsible pane and components under it do not respond to mouse events, i.e. i cannot expand/collapse the pane or interact with components under CollapsiblePane.

Below is the sample code. Try to toggle checkboxes under collapsiblePane, they do not react

```
import wx
import sys
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):        
        wx.Frame.__init__( self, None, -1, "My Frame" )  # , size=(300,300)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=2, hgap=5, vgap=5)
        CB1 = wx.CheckBox( self.panel, -1, "dene-1")
        CB2 = wx.CheckBox( self.panel, -1, "dene-2")

        CP = wx.CollapsiblePane(self, -1, label="TITLE", style=wx.CP_DEFAULT_STYLE|wx.CP_NO_TLW_RESIZE)  
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COLLAPSIBLEPANE_CHANGED, self.OnPaneChanged, CP)       
        win = CP.GetPane()        
        pansizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )       
        cb1 = wx.CheckBox( win, -1, "enable 1")
        cb2 = wx.CheckBox( win, -1, "enable 2")        
        pansizer.Add( cb1, 0, wx.GROW | wx.ALL  )
        pansizer.Add( cb2, 0, wx.GROW | wx.ALL )        
        win.SetSizer( pansizer )        
        pansizer.SetSizeHints(win)
        CP.Expand()

        sizer.Add( CB1, 0, wx.ALL )
        sizer.Add( CB2, 0, wx.ALL )        
        sizer.Add( CP, 0, wx.RIGHT|wx.LEFT|wx.EXPAND, 5 )            
        self.panel.SetSizer( sizer )
        self.panel.Fit()

    def OnPaneChanged(self, evt):
        # redo the layout
        self.Layout()           


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a self.panel object, but created your collapsible pane as a child of your frame.
You need to change how your window updates.  First the sizer must layout then you must fit your panel, and then fit your window.  Code is posted below.  I changed the size of the frame so that you can see the expanding and collapsing of the pane.

```
def __init__(self):        
    wx.Frame.__init__( self, None, -1, "My Frame" )  # , size=(300,300)

    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

    sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=2, hgap=5, vgap=5)
    CB1 = wx.CheckBox( self.panel, -1, "dene-1")
    CB2 = wx.CheckBox( self.panel, -1, "dene-2")

    CP = wx.CollapsiblePane(self.panel, -1, label="TITLE", style=wx.CP_DEFAULT_STYLE|wx.CP_NO_TLW_RESIZE)  
    CP.Bind(wx.EVT_COLLAPSIBLEPANE_CHANGED, self.OnPaneChanged)       
    win = CP.GetPane()        
    pansizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )       
    cb1 = wx.CheckBox( win, -1, "enable 1")
    cb2 = wx.CheckBox( win, -1, "enable 2")        
    pansizer.Add( cb1, 0, wx.GROW | wx.ALL  )
    pansizer.Add( cb2, 0, wx.GROW | wx.ALL )        
    win.SetSizer( pansizer )        
    pansizer.SetSizeHints(win)
    CP.Collapse()

    sizer.Add( CB1, 0, wx.ALL )
    sizer.Add( CB2, 0, wx.ALL )        
    sizer.Add( CP, 0, wx.RIGHT|wx.LEFT|wx.EXPAND, 5 )            
    self.panel.SetSizerAndFit( sizer )
    self.Fit()

def OnPaneChanged(self, evt):
    # redo the layout
    self.panel.GetSizer().Layout()
    self.panel.Fit()
    self.Fit()
```

if **name**=="**main**":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()